# How to fire Flux actions for RelayMutations

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux, graphql, relayjs

In other words, How can I get local state (flux stores such as ModalStore, HistoryStore etc) to update upon relay mutation. Only solution I could find is to use callbacks to fire flux actions. However this becomes very redundant and dangerous, since I have to fire an action every time that mutation is used and, that piece of code depends on the shape of the mutation payload. I have a feeling that there is a much better solution that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before heading off to the server, every mutation goes through the `sendMutation` method of the network layer. One solution could be to intercept mutations there, then fire optimistic, commit, and rollback Flux actions.

Presuming that for every single Relay mutation named `FooMutation` you have three corresponding Flux actions called `RelayMutationActions.(doOptimistic|commit|rollback)FooMutation`, something like this might work:

```js
var myNetworkLayer = {
  ...Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer,
  sendMutation(mutationRequest) {
    // Pluck the mutation from the outgoing request
    const mutation = mutationRequest.getMutation();
    const mutationName = mutation.getName();
    const mutationPayload = mutation.getVariables().input;

    // Fire an optimistic Flux action immediately
    RelayMutationActions[`doOptimistic${mutationName}`](mutationPayload);

    // Pass the request on to the default network layer implementation
    return Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer.sendMutation(mutationRequest)
      .then(payload =>
        if (payload.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
          // If there was an error, fire a new rollback Flux action
          RelayMutationActions[`rollback${mutationName}`](payload);
        } else {
          // Otherwise fire a Flux action that commits the transaction
          RelayMutationActions[`commit${mutationName}`](payload);
        }
      );
  },
};
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(myNetworkLayer);
```

Comment: This is a great global solution, however I also found that the Relay.Store.Update(FooMutation(), {onSuccess: () => { //handle success }, onFailure: () => { //handle failure} }) works well on a more specific scale. Thoughts?

Comment: Oh, for sure; that's another design. I thought that when you said “…this becomes very redundant and dangerous, since I have to fire an action every time that mutation is used” you were indicating that you wanted to avoid such a localized solution.

Comment: Oops! Sorry… it was @OguzBilgic who said that, not you!

Comment: Yeah I didn't ask the question just started the bounty. I didn't understand the OP's solution fully until after I started the bounty. Your solution fits the original question! Thanks :)